# What exactly does standard deviation mean in this dataset, and how do I go about generating it in another?

Tags: r, standard-deviation, standard-error, boxplot

I'm trying to add error bars to a boxplot in R. I need sd/se and all of the instructions I can find that I can understand have datasets with sd/se already calculated, like so:
[image: img]

My dataset is set up the same way as this one, but I'm confused as to what the "sd" and "se" columns are referring to and how to calculate them from my own data to generate that column?

Comment: Although this comment is tangential to your objectives, could you explain what an "error bar" might mean for a *boxplot?*

Answer (score 0):

SD is a common abbreviation for Standard Deviation, while SE is Standard Error. Standard Deviation ($\sigma$) is the measure of average distance from the mean in a distribution.

SE is the SD of a sample that is proportional to the sample size (n): $SE = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$

The equation for $\sigma$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\Sigma(x_i-\mu)^2}{n}}$, where $\mu$ is the mean of the group. To calculate the standard deviation of your groups in R, simple use the [sd function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/sd). There is also a convenient [se function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotrix/versions/3.8-2/topics/std.error).

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I know what sd stands for and I know I can use sd() to find an sd for a given variable (i.e. it would be very simple to use sd(data$Activity) to get an sd for that column. But what do I put in the parentheses of the function sd() to get an individual sd for each observation, as in the sd column in the table I provided? I don't quite understand what each individual sd in that table means (i.e. how you can have a standard deviation for an individual observation).

Comment: @HES we don't calculate standard deviations for individual observations. The SDs in your table are for those groups of size N. For example, row 1 is females with genotype ff have a standard deviation in activity of 0.96

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch I missed the 'N'. I'm guessing the other data sets I've seen are the same way then.

Comment: @HES no problem, and yea I would be surprised if they were missing that.

Answer (score 0):

The standard deviation is quantity we compute for a GROUP of observations, with respect to a particular variable. It tells us how far, "on average" each observation's value for that variable in the group is from the overall average for that variable. So a group of 1,000 people might have an average "activity" score of 3.5. Of course, that is just an average, some people in the group are going to have more or less activity than that. The standard deviation tells us how "tightly" these values are clustered around the overall average. If the standard deviation of activity for this group was 0.5, that tells us the average person in this group has a score that is 0.5 points higher or lower than 3.5.

The standard error is a modification of the standard error which is used in calculating various statistical measures of uncertainty.

For this reason, it doesn't make sense to calculate a standard deviation (or standard error) for a single observation. As the comments mentioned, in the table provided each row represents a single type of observation, with a particular set of characteristics. And the table includes the "N" (number of observations) in each group, which allows you to calculate the standard deviation (and standard error) for each group.